# how to encode contract invoke parameter to json code? ConseilJS not support parameter of tyep List Signature

Tags: michelson, conseil, micheline

ConseilJS seems not support parameter type List Signature, see at https://github.com/Cryptonomic/ConseilJS/issues/261.

So I want to encode my parameter to JSON code that I can change parameterType from `conseilJS.TezosParameterFormat.Michelson` to `conseilJS.TezosParameterFormat.Micheline`. But I don't know how to encode my parameter to tezos required JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
  "prim": "Pair",
  "args": [
    {
      "prim": "Pair",
      "args": [
        {
          "prim": "Pair",
          "args": [
            {
              "int": "1200000"
            },
            [
              {
                "string": "edsigteSbYS1LWAJue2RhoczKG8C48imf8Nag1bxrifqr1yAteYencA6BfwMgud1A8Z76iG2YSqQxMUXiXXMCNtNkYQvRzzsSFV"
              },
              {
                "string": "edsigtrVeUQqMs9Uw8QuwNHJb37yKZA1BsnwtRxbyXF7KAQzf3CbrCuXbgLpG1pbZzeK7HTrPTPhfe3pKUGoDkAo7Aczd6GKCwX"
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        {
          "string": "tz1WfxXzNgcsMrQBV6YHChmyQgNVvfo44ihi"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "string": "123123123"
    }
  ]
}
```